# How to specify types in javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

**Hi!** My problem is that when you prompt a number and add it to another prompt is uses the "+" operator to join the lines. I want it to add the numbers together. How can I do this?

```js
alert(prompt('add a number') + prompt('add another number'));
```

Thanks in advance,
TheCoder

Comment: The `prompt()` function always returns a string, so you have to explicitly make the return values be numbers. You can do that by writing `+prompt("...")` instead of just `prompt("...")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use parseInt or parseFloat

```
alert(parseInt(prompt('add a number')) + prompt(parseInt('add another number')));
```

Comment: `parseFloat()`?

Comment: It's `parseFloat()` not `parseDouble()`, also those functions are not always the best things to use because they allow trailing non-numeric text; `"123hello"` will not cause an error.

Comment: I would maybe extend this answer by adding a check that the `parseInt` actually succeeded -- otherwise you risk adding `NaN`, or as @Pointy mentioned, falsely detecting `123hello` as a number. Something like `var input_one = prompt(...); var input_two = prompt(...); if (!isNaN(parseInt(input_one)) && parseInt(input_one).toString() === input_one && !isNaN(parseInt(input_two)) && parseInt(input_two).toString() === input_two) { alert(parseInt(input_one) + parseInt(input_two)); };`

Comment: @stevendesu In something more complex, I agree checking for NaN does make sense... maybe throw an exception. But for a simple case, I think if you ask the user for 2 numbers to sum together and they enter bad input, NaN to me is fine

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a string to a number with the `+` operator, like so:

```
+"50" + +"40" = 90
```

The result will be `NaN` if the strings can't be converted to a number (ie, `+"fifty" => NaN`), so you'll want to account for that in your code.

```
alert(+prompt('add a number') + +prompt('add another number'));
```

Comment: I would note that using the `+` operator like this is **technically** considered a "hack" (even though it's defined in the ECMAScript specification and therefore isn't subject to breaking like many hacks), and it can make your code less readable. I would instead suggest using `parseInt` or `parseFloat`

Comment: That's a nice shorthand

Comment: @stevendesu In my experience, the `+` operator is far more common than the other methods, so I would say that although it may be hacky, it's an accepted standard practice and is therefore probably more recognizable (although admittedly less readable).

Comment: thanks for the help. Check out the site I needed that for @ http://novaos.tk